# _?NumericQ inside NDSolve to speed up code

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

I've seen some people using `_?NumericQ` to prevent symbolic calculation and speed up  `NDSolve`.
Why in this simple code is not working ?

```
qlist = {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5};
q0 = {0, 0, 0, 3, 2};
q[t_] = ToString@# <> "[t]" & /@ qlist // ToExpression;

f[{q1_?NumericQ, q2_?NumericQ, q3_?NumericQ, q4_?NumericQ, 
   q5_?NumericQ}] := {Cos@q3, Sin@q3, 1, 0, 0}

NDSolve[{q'[t] == f@q[t], q[0] == q0}, q[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

I just get the error

```
NDSolve:"There are more dependent variables, {q1[t],q2[t],q3[t],q4[t],q5[t]}, 
than equations, so the system is underdetermined"
```

I'll better explain with a second exmple:

```
Pmat = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> "p" <> ToString@i <> ToString@j, {5, 
     5}] // ToExpression;

P[t_] = Array[ToString@Pmat[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]" &, Dimensions@Pmat] // 
   ToExpression;

P0 = IdentityMatrix[5];

RHS := P[t].P[t] + IdentityMatrix[5] // Inverse // Inverse

NDSolve[{P[0] == P0, P'[t] == RHS}, P[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

Here Mathematica spend a huge amount of time due to the symbolic evaluation. I'm asking if is there a way to bypass this process.The problem inside is very simple because the initial condition is a diagonal matrix. 
I've tried this approach tho overcome the issue:

```
Pmat = SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> "p" <> ToString@i <> ToString@j, {5, 
     5}] // ToExpression;

P[t_] = Array[ToString@Pmat[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]" &, Dimensions@Pmat] // 
   ToExpression;

P0 = IdentityMatrix[5];

RHS[Pi_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
 Pi.Pi + IdentityMatrix[5] // Inverse // Inverse

NDSolve[{P[0] == P0, P'[t] == RHS[P[t]]}, P[t], {t, 0, 3}]

(*NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {p11[t],p12[t],p13[t],p14[t],p15[t],p21[t],p22[t],p23[t],p24[t],p25[t],p31[t],p32[t],p33[t],p34[t],p35[t],p41[t],p42[t],p43[t],p44[t],p45[t],p51[t],p52[t],p53[t],p54[t],p55[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.*)
```

But the code doesn't run.
This one is a sort of simulink approach, is there a way to make Mathematica work as it was in simulink, with a numerical approach, maybe using Module to calculate the RHS of a ODE system ?

Is possible to prevent symbolic evaluation inside NDSovle ? is my approach wrong ?

Comment: I guess that form is not supported, but this vector form is: `NDSolve[{qq'[t] == f@qq[t], qq[0] == q0}, qq[t], {t, 0, 3}]` (Please include error messages, when your code produces them.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of `f`

```
qlist = {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5};
q0 = {0, 0, 0, 3, 2};
q[t_] = ToString@# <> "[t]" & /@ qlist //ToExpression;
f = Function[q, {Cos[q[[3]]], Sin[q[[3]]], 1, 0,0}];
NDSolve[{q'[t] == f@q[t], q[0] == q0}, q[t], {t,0, 3}]
```

Comment: You could just remove the `_?NumericQ` from the OP's `f`, too, no?

Comment: Yes, the fact is that i'd want numerical evaluation before the symbolic one, I've seen several codes which use this technique. I've tried to replicate them but I got error

Comment: I think an idiomatic way to get `{q1[t], q2[t], q3[t], q4[t], q5[t]}` is to use `Through[qlist[t]]`

Comment: @yarchik - or `#[t] & /@ qlist`

Comment: @yarchik thanks for the advice !